# How can I broadcast with websockets? (python)

Tags: python, websocket

So, I'm trying to make a simple chatroom with websockets using python.
Right now, the server (websocket) can only see all the messages sent and the clients can only see the messages they send. How can I broadcast with websockets? I've tried searching through the docs but couldn't find it. Is this possible to do and if so how do I do it?

websocket code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo(websocket):
 async for message in websocket:
    await websocket.send(message)
    print(message)

async def main():
 async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 8765):
    await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())




def delete_last_line():
    "Use this function to delete the last line in the STDOUT"

    #cursor up one line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')

    #delete last line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')

async def echo(websocket):
 async for message in websocket:
    await websocket.send(message)
    print(message)

username = input('Username:')
delete_last_line()
if username == 'Default Box':
 username = f'{Fore.BLUE}☆ Default Box{Fore.WHITE}'
 print(f'Set your username to {username}')
 print('Connecting to the chatroom...')

async def hello(message_sent):
 async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
    await websocket.send(message_sent)
    msg = await websocket.recv()
    print(msg)

async def checkformessages():
 async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)
        print(message)

message = f'{username} {Fore.YELLOW}has joined the chatroom{Fore.WHITE}'
asyncio.run(hello(message))

while True:
 message_input = input()
 message = f'{username}: {message_input}'
 delete_last_line()
 asyncio.run(hello(message))
 message = None`
```

Client code ^

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in broadcast. Just loop through all the connections in the server, sending to each of them.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: In the server, when you get a new connection, append it to a list of all connections. When you want to broadcast, loop through all the connections, and call `socket.send(message)`